# Character "w" in ubuntu terminal sudenly does not show

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

Suddenly I realized that on my Ubuntu terminal ( 14 LTS ) every instance of character "w" does not appear correctly. [image]

I've noticed that gedit behaves the same (shows a broken w), however "w" does not appear broken in xterm. Both terminal and gedit uses the Monospace 12 font.

Anyone knows what might be the cause, or where to look for this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Is this only in the terminal? Does it also appear in other programs? How about other terminals (try `xterm`)?

Comment: I noticed that gedit behaves the same (shows a broken w), however. "w" does not appear broken  in xterm.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and include this information. Also tell us if you're using the same font in `gedit` and the terminal.

Comment: I do not know how to check the fonts in either

Comment: For `gnome-terminal` it's Edit => Profile Preferences => General and for `gedit` it's Preferences => Font & Colors.

Comment: I have the same issue: Broken characters in both terminal and gedit. The issue went away after I changed the font from Monospace Bold to Monospace.